# Have Devas like Indra, Agni, Varun ever done tapasya in order to counter attack Asuras?

Tags: gods, indra, asuras, agni, tapasya

We all know that asuras like Mahisasura, Hiranyakashipu, Tarakasur and many others did severe tapasya to impress either Brahma, Vishnu or Mahesh in order to seek various powers/boon so that they could use them against Devas but do we have any  references from scriptures or other authentic sources of Devas like Indra, Varun, Agni etc. doing severe tapasya to seek extra ordinary powers/boon in order to counter attack Asuras?

Asking this coz what I figure out from the mythological series is that whenever the Devas were under threat they always sought help either from Brahma, Vishnu or Mahesh and looked weak against the powerful asuras. It gives a wrong impression, if they can not defend themselves then how come they can defend others? It appears as if Asuras were more powerful and competent than the Devas. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: It’s not that devas can not defend themselves. It’s about respecting the boon given by Trimurti. Their inability to get victory over asuras creates the opportunity for avatars. How can Devas be weak if Lord is always their to help them. Their power is in being humble and asking for help. :-)

Comment: So if we take out Trimurti from the scenario then Devas can easily defeat Asuras? @Ketan

Comment: Yes and your question answers that. Like you said Asuras did tapsya to get boon/power from Trimurti to fight Devas. Take out Trimurti from scenario then asura wouldn’t get the power to fight devas. :-) But this is my understanding. I eagerly await for scriptural answer.

Comment: Why do you add scripture for every question of yours? It is enough if you ask you want answers from authentic sources. It should be used when you ask about scriptures itself.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Why is that an issue if you can please elaborate a bit?

Comment: It is about accurate tagging. If one clicks on scripture for question about texts and finds it is about Devatas, they will be disappointed. Tagging should be precise and perfect and help readers. I can't tag [website] because I want references from website. Same here. There have been many discussions about this. see [meta-tag:tags] for info.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma what if I am seeking references from scriptures?

Comment: Add a line that you want answers from scriptures or other authentic sources. You should add scripture when you are asking question about scripture. This is a question about Devas.. A line is enough. Tag is not needed. Tags have many later effects. Tags should not indicate the correctness or the source we want the answers from. It indicates what the question is about. You have added it in your previous ones too. They can be answered from many authentic books by scholars, swamijis which are not scriptures.. So adding a statement is enough.

Comment: Ok np will update the question.

Comment: @Just_Do_It They all did tapsya thats why they got those posts..so edited title to be more specific...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## References of Devas like Indra, Varun, Agni etc. doing severe tapasya to seek extra ordinary powers/boon in order to counter attack Asuras.

Yes in in [**Brahmanda**](https://archive.org/stream/BrahmandaPuranaG.V.TagarePart4/Brahmanda%20Purana%20-%20G.V.Tagare%20-%20Part%204#page/n135) Purana there is a story of Indra and all the devas performing a penance at the slopes of  Himalaya in order to defeat Asura leader Bhandasura and all the other asuras , Who  is later Killed By Devi Lalitha an incarnation of Shree Adi-Parashakti in a battle.

Brief Account of the Story -:

When Bhandasura got the boon from Lord Shiva that  half of his opponents power in the battle will be united with himself and his arrows will make the opponents missiles and weapons futile.

He became powerful after receiving the boon and became the leader of Daityas. He performed all the Vedic activities and tapas for sixteen thousand years. Now he was becoming more powerful than the devas day by day. Indra got  worried about the increasing power of Asuras and due to his deteriorating condition. Lord Vishnu by seeing Asuras influence and possibility of them of conquering three worlds created Maya and asked her to enter into the demon and thus Asuras were deluded.

Once Narada visited Indra and told him that Lord Vishnu's maya is residing in Demon Bhandasura , if he is somehow liberated from this maya he will overcome the three worlds. And this task cant be carried out without the help of Adi-Parashakti (supreme goddess) .And   Asked him to do penance to get the help of the goddess in defeating him. So Indra with all the gods did the penance at Himalaya. They did the penance for Ten Thousand and Ten days.

> 43 Accompanied by all the devas he made due preparations for penance
>   and went to the slopes of Himavan.
>
> 44 Along with all the gods he performed the great worship of
>   Parashakti on the bank of Bhagirathi that was brilliant with flowers
>   in everyone of the seasons. Even since then that place bestowing all
>   sorts of accomplishments came to known by the name Indraprastha.
>
> 45-46  In accordance with the procedure advised by the son of Brahma ,
>   they performed the excellent and great worship of the goddess.They
>   were engage in Japa (repetition of holy names and mantras) and
>   mediation .They were steadyfast in severe penance without turning
>   their mind or attention on anything else. Thus ten ten thousand years
>   and ten days passed by.

---

[**Chandogya Upanishad**](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/chhand/ch_4d.html) is also   having an interesting story in it about Indra and Virochana approaching Brahmadeva to know the nature of the self -Chapter 4: An Analysis of the Nature of the Self , It is mentioned  in that Lord Brahma asked Indra to  perform Tapas /penance many times  ,when he was having some doubts about what is Atma or self i.e.  to learn the truth about the Atman

So indra in total did one hundred and one years of tapasya  in the abode of Prajapati while he was clearing the doubts about  Atman or the  Self.

And its because of this true  knowledge of the self Indra and devas gained many victories in battle against Asuras.

---

Your other  question basically enquires about how Devas were defeated by Daityas and how they have fled many times form the war to take shelter to Trimurtis.

> "It appears that if they can not defend themselves then how come they
>   can defend others? It appears as if Asuras were more powerful and
>   competent than the Devas."

But it is not the case every time. As said by you the Asuras by their individual Tapas or penance satisfied /pleased either one of the Trimurti ( Brahma- Vishnu-Mahesha) and obtained peculier boon so that they can not be defeated or get killed in normal situations. And those asuras then became the leaders of Asura race and due to their boon  they and their followers were able to defeat  gods many times in battles. **As the boons were given by the Trimurtis the Gods naturally went to them for the alternate solution to overcome the troubles caused by the Asuras and in the meantime not to override the boon given by Trimurties .**

[**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01065.htm) also tells us something  different . In Adi Parva- Amsha Avataraana parva-Chapter 64 -Verse 28- it is mentioned that previously in Satya-Yuga Devas (sons of Aditi) defeated Daityas many a times.

> आदित्यैर्ही तदा दैत्या बहुशो निर्जिता: युधि |
>  ऐश्वर्याद भ्रन्शिता:
>   स्वर्गात सम्बभूवु: क्षिताविह || 1.64.28 ||
>
> "And, O bull of the Bharata race, when such was the blessed state of
>   the terrestrial world, the Asuras, O lord of men, began to be born in
>   kingly lines. And the sons of Diti (Daityas) being repeatedly defeated
>   in war by the sons of Aditi (celestials) and deprived also of
>   sovereignty and heaven, began to be incarnated on the earth.

So in conclusion devas were not always weak in position but due to the boons  and powers and devotion of Asuras they were unable to fight with them alone without help of the three Gods and win the battle , without taking permission or the help of Trimurties.

Comment: Very well explained.